# How to manually find the contents of a register after a Hex code instruction

Tags: assembly, hex

Given the following state of memory in hexadecimal:

```
0001 A2 |
0002 11 |
0003 00 |
0004 FF |
```

What are the contents of the A register after the execution of these instructions:

a) c1 00 01        Answer: A2 11

b) c1 00 02        Answer: 11 00

We are given 5 memory locations:

```
A2 11 |    A2 12 |
00 02 |    11 00 |
00 FF |
```

OK! So our teach gave us the answer's to the questions above however the problem I am having is that I do not know how to validate these answers. He did not explain to us on how to get them and I have asked for help on this multiple times with no answer from him. Myself and a few students have an open discussion of this on the school forums and will be grateful for any direction or an explanation.

I am guessing that C1 is an op code and the operands are memory locations for 1 and 2. I can not find anywhere in the chapter that states as such or the appendix explaining what C1 means.

Pep/8 is the assembler and simulator that is being used for the instruction set I believe.

Comment: find the op codes, then execute a dry run of them

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Are you aware that assembly is processor specific? There exists no standard for encoding instructions which is valid for all processors in existence. Same with register names. 6809 CPU has an A register - do you code for those?

Comment: The [instruction set reference](https://code.google.com/p/pep8-1/wiki/InstructionSet) lists the opcodes. `C1` is `LDBYTEA`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr My question is how do I reason that the answer is A2 11 for the instructions of "a)" given the memory locations?

Comment: @Bushmills No, I was  unaware as a matter of fact but I love learning something new; that it was processor specific. Thank you for helping me in that regard. I have barely any knowledge in assembly language and pep/8, I mainly work in C++ so thank you for all your comments and patience.

Comment: @Jester I do not see LDBYTEA is it LDBYTEr instead? Also I can not see where C1 is referenced at all on the Pep/8-1 instructions set provided. By the way, thank you for that link.

Comment: Yes, `LDBYTEr` but the `r` comes from the opcode. Actually I made a mistake, `C1` is of course `LDA` given that `C1=1100 0001`. The `r` bit selects `A` or `X` register.